# Simplest lowercase example for es keyword type

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to ignore case on searches. What would be the least verbose way to do this. For example, something like:

```
"mappings": {
  "_doc": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {"type": "keyword", "analyzer": "ignore_case"}
    }
  }
}
```

The above is pseudo-code but what would be the best way to do this? Basically I want to have a word like:

```
"Hello"
```

And have "Hello" or "HELLO" or "hELlo" or "hello" match it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keyword datatype doesn't use `Analyzers`. You need to make use of `Normalizer`

If you intend to make use of `keyword` in that case you need to create a custom [Normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html) with `filter` configured as `lowercase` and your mapping should be as follows:

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{  
   "settings":{  
      "analysis":{  
         "normalizer":{  
            "my_custom_normalizer":{  
               "type":"custom",
               "filter":[  
                  "lowercase"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "mydocs":{  
         "properties":{  
            "mytext":{  
               "type":"keyword",
               "normalizer":"my_custom_normalizer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I think that is the least verbose way! Hope it helps!